# How to set value to label/text

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to do basic calculation for a program and I want the output to be in the label and some in text boxes, how do I do that?? parts of the code are as below. There are other things that add to the quantity but I only show this one.

```
int quantity = 0;
int sum = 0;

if(jToggleButton3.isSelected())

    {
        quantity = quantity + 1;
    }

    sum = quantity;

    quantityLabel = quantity;
    sumLabel = sum;
```

I want the quantity and sum to be output both in labels, how can I do that?? In vb it's like lblquantity.text = quantity; but here I have no idea and I can't find any links that teach this(Also what is the proper naming convention)

Edit: Thanks a lot guys, got it working !

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Did you try `lblquantity.setText(""+quantity)` ?

Comment: I'm trying to output the value from quantity and sum to 2 labels respectively

Comment: Check [Variables Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) for proper naming conventions.

Comment: Since you got it working you should accept one of the answers below.

Answer (score 2):

```
lblquantity.setText(""+quantity);
```

should do the job. Or better :

```
lblquantity.setText(Integer.toString(quantity));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure how to use a class just check the documentation online.

You can find it here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html

It says that the JLabel has a SetText method, which can be used to cahnge the text.
You can do it like this:

```
yourlabel.setText("new text");
```

Of course you need a reference to your JLabel object.

If you want to put an integer value on your JLabel you have to convert it to string.

```
yourlabel.setText(Integer.toString(quantity));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setText(String)` method:

```
quantityLabel.setText("Quantity = " + quantity);
sumLabel.setText("Sum = " + sum);
```

This is assuming `quantityLabel` and `sumLabel` are instances of `JLabel` or a subclass of it.